# webdriver.io afterscenario close browser now working

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, wdio-v4

Using webdriverIO and I am trying to close / quit chrome browser between scenarios.  Here is what I have in the conf file:

```
  afterScenario: function (scenario) {
        console.log("afterScenario quit browser");
        browser.Close();
        ;
    },
```

Is there a way to close browser or chromedriver after each scenario with wdio?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each WebdriverIO process opens a new session (`browser.sessionId`). Thus, the [reload()](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/utility/reload.html) function is what you are probably looking for.

```
afterScenario: function (scenario) {
  console.log("After scenario, reload session!");
  browser.reload();
},
```

**!Note:** For people running the newer `wdio-v5` version, the corresponding API command is [reloadSession](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/reloadSession.html).

Answer (score 1):

We have did the other way around. Restarting new browser/chrome session as part scenario whenever required using the below command:

```
const status = browser.status();
if(status.value.ready){
        browser.reload();
}
```

And also just to add. `browser.close()` is used as part of windowHandles. `browser.end()` is the one which can be used for closing a browser but unfortunately it is supported only on standalone mode.